# How to check if a number is prime in C++

Tags: c++, loops, boolean, primes

to me this code looks correct, but when i run it all the output it gives me is "2". I've tried looking it over several times but each time i don't find anything wrong. So I'm wondering if someone wouldn't mind looking over the following code to let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool oddOrEven(int x)
{
    int divisor = 2; // initial divisor check
    bool boolCheck = true; // initial boolean value set to true, later to check

    for(int i = x-1; i >= 2;i--)
    {
        if(i%divisor == 0)
            boolCheck = false;
    }

    return boolCheck; // returning whether or not the number is prime
}


int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter how many numbers you want to check: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Prime numbers from 2-" << num1 << endl;

    for(int i=num1; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        if(oddOrEven(i))
            cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like it might have something to do with my bool check, but I'm not 100% what.

EDIT: Before even posting this i realized i did not increase the divisor, so i tried that and it's still not coming out right. All i changed was this:

```
for(int i = x-1; i >= 2;i--)
{
    if(i%divisor == 0)
        boolCheck = false;
    divisor = divisor + 1;
}
```

So I am still stuck, once again any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. "oddOrEven" == the set of all numbers.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean, haha. Do you mean when I use oddOrEven(i)?

Comment: I mean `oddOrEven(x)` seems to indicate `isOdd(x) || isEven(x)` which is always `true`.

Comment: Also that you only need to check up to `sqrt(n)`, not `n`.

Comment: yeah i knew the sqrt(n) thing, but i didn't know if i could just write that in like that. Or if i would need another library, like #include <math> or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing wrong numbers. Change this line

```
if(i%divisor == 0)
```

to

```
if (x % i == 0)
```

That being said, as you probably know your algorithm is far from optimal. At least you can `return false` immediately instead of setting the flag. You can check divisors only up to square root of `x`. You can check only odd divisors. [And so on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: Wow... I feel so stupid, that fixed it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @BpVx You can just return false instead of set boolCheck to false it will stop an unneeded loop. just saying :)